# How to modify which keys make the grub menu appear

Tags: grub2, shortcut-keys

Sometime I need to access grub. I have the timeout to 0 but I can still call the grub menu by pressing <kbd>ESC</kbd> or leaving <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> pressed. What I want is to change that so for example, to get the grub menu I would need to press another key or key combination.

I do not wish to change the grub menu timeout. I like it to boot fast, all I want is a way to make the key or keys to show the grub changed to another combination.

Comment: I've seen people touching the source code for this. As far as I know, this is not configurable.

Comment: Yeah also saw stuff like that, but since it was 2 years ago I am asking again just in case.

Comment: Isn't it that now **any** key pressed will bring up the Grub menu?

Comment: Just tried **any** key and GRUB laughed at the face of danger (For example spacebar, enter, backspace, H, F, X, Z... even F1). I then presses ESC or SHIFT and GRUB cried